# Easiest way to open a download window without navigating away from the page

Tags: javascript

What is the best cross browser way to open a download dialog (let's assume we can set content-disposion:attachment in the headers) without navigating away from the current page, or opening popups, which doesn't work well in Internet Explorer(IE) 6.

Answer (score 145, accepted):

7 years have passed and
I don't know whether it works for IE6 or not, but this prompts OpenFileDialog in FF and Chrome.

```
var file_path = 'host/path/file.ext';
var a = document.createElement('A');
a.href = file_path;
a.download = file_path.substr(file_path.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
document.body.appendChild(a);
a.click();
document.body.removeChild(a);
```

Comment: First thank you for this solution, but I found a bug if removeChild(a) the zip will unzip error with zip is broken, so remove this code solve it

Comment: , but A tag will more and more, so how do I check download is done?

Comment: safari has a problem with `a.click();`

Comment: had to change the line `var a = document.createElement('A');` to `let a = document.createElement('a');` to get it to work in angular 2 typescript

Comment: +1 There is no apparent need to add the `a` element to `document.body` for it to work as intended. Also, tried this approach in Chrome (64.0.3282.167) and Safari (11.0.3) -- worked in both cases.

Comment: this is not working for firefox. how to download in firefox ?

Comment: @Manoj Rana - I have checked on FF 58.0.2 (64-bit) it is working. It won't work on any FF if you remove 2 lines _document.body.appendChild(a);_ _document.body.removeChild(a);_

Comment: To make it work on Edge 16 the header, from where the file comes, should contains `Content-Type: application/octet-stream` and `Content-Disposition: attachment`.

Comment: this doesnt work anymore https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/02/chrome-65-deprecations

Comment: @user1933131 chrome removes only for cross-origin

Comment: @Simon thanks for your comment! It solved my problem for Edge 44, although I didn't need the `Content-Disposition` header for Edge 42.

Comment: Great answers. Additional Question for your solution. It is possible to use a different Download-Filename ?

Comment: @TheAlphaGhost you can do it on a server side

Comment: @PauliusDragunas It still works. But it does not work for cross-origin urls.

Comment: Does not work also for untrusted(self-signed) SSL

Comment: do you know how to unit test this with jest and Testing Library?

Answer (score 247):

This javascript is nice that it doesn't open a new window or tab.

```
window.location.assign(url);
```

Comment: This is the same as window.location = url; “Whenever a new value is assigned to the location object, a document will be loaded using the URL as if window.location.assign() had been called with the modified URL” - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.location

Comment: This causes WebSocket connection to disconnect.

Comment: I have used the same solution but it opens file in same tab instead of opening a download dialog.

Comment: it's same to window.open(url, '_self') if the url is for download page then.

Comment: When using IE11 I found that this caused JS to stop. So for IE 11 I used window.open(url, '_blank') which did open another tab, however that tab closed when it worked out the file was a download. This kept the JS running.

Comment: this is the best answer i've come across.

I use typescript, axios and react and this is just what I needed.

I just want to amend that I needed this code to complete the work

``` .       let blob = new Blob([response.data], { type: 'text/csv' });
            let link = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            window.location.assign(link);```

Comment: Thanks, it's smart and working perfectly, no need to create temporary <href>

Answer (score 51):

I know the question was asked `7 years and 9 months ago` but many posted solutions doesn't seem to work, for example using an `<iframe>` works only with `FireFox` and doesn't work with `Chrome`.

**Best solution:**

The best [**working solution**](https://jsfiddle.net/chsdk/0pvdvssd/) to open a file download pop-up in `JavaScript` is to use a `HTML` link element, *with no need to append the link element to the `document.body`* as stated in other answers.

You can use the following function:

```
function downloadFile(filePath){
    var link=document.createElement('a');
    link.href = filePath;
    link.download = filePath.substr(filePath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    link.click();
}
```

In my application, I am using it this way:

```
downloadFile('report/xls/myCustomReport.xlsx');
```

**Working Demo:**

```js
function downloadFile(filePath) {
  var link = document.createElement('a');
  link.href = filePath;
  link.download = filePath.substr(filePath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
  link.click();
}

downloadFile("http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/accessibility/pdfs/accessing-pdf-sr.pdf");
```

**Note:**

- You have to use the `link.download` attribute so the browser doesn't
  open the file in a new tab and fires the download pop-up.
- This was tested with several file types (docx, xlsx, png, pdf, ...).

Comment: What would be the best way to display a loading gif until the file has downloaded?

Comment: @Ctrl_Alt_Defeat Well in this case it won't be easy to track the download process, but one trick can be to show this gif animation on the `link` click and hide it after a timeout, using this code: `link.onclick = function() {
    document.body.innerText = "The file is being downloaded ...";
    setTimeout(function() {
      document.body.innerText = "";
    }, 2000);
  }`, you can see it working [in **this fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/chsdk/0pvdvssd/6/), but keep in mind that it's not a recommended way to do it, it would be better handled if we were using `Ajax`.

Comment: it's not work in firefox. how to download  in firefox ?

Comment: @ManojRana For firefox, you can use an `iframe` see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18064978/3669624).

Comment: This solution works in Chrome, Safari and Firefox for me :)

Comment: this looks like the best approach for my case

Comment: Thanks @cнŝdk!
I deleted my previous comment, as I found that there are other things that PWA breaks while on the way to `document.createElement()`. If I clean them up, the method still works.

Comment: @iva2k cool, glad to hear that it works for you.

Comment: Nice and simple, only works for same origin downloads: https://developer.chrome.com/blog/chrome-65-deprecations#block_cross-origin_a_download

Answer (score 33):

I always add a target="_blank" to the download link. This will open a new window, but as soon as the user clicks save, the new window is closed.

Comment: This is the best answer.  In Internet Explorer, adding the 'target="_blank"' to a link that is to be downloadedwill stop the browser from navigating away (where "HTML1300: Navigation occurred" is printed), and thus can leave the page in an inconsistent state.

Answer (score 26):

Put this in the HTML head section, setting the `url` var to the URL of the file to be downloaded:

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
function startDownload()  
{  
     var url='http://server/folder/file.ext';    
     window.open(url, 'Download');  
}  
</script>
```

Then put this in the body, which will start the download automatically after 5 seconds:

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
setTimeout('startDownload()', 5000); //starts download after 5 seconds  
</script>
```

(From [here](http://www.dslreports.com/forum/r21478709-).)

Comment: that doesnt work, because in IE6, if the user clicks "save" the file is saved, but the popup stays open. This is not acceptable.

Comment: this code is not working in safari can you help me to resolved in safari please.

Comment: It is opening in New Window in Browser. Is it possible to download automatically.??? Thanks

Comment: This no longer works in the year of our Lord 2022

Comment: This worked for me but I started getting weird glitchy behavior in my debug browser when I'd attempt to open multiple files (one after the other) somewhat rapidly.

Answer (score 19):

I've been looking for a good way to use javascript to initiate the download of a file, just as this question suggests.  However these answers not been helpful.    I then did some xbrowser testing and have found that an iframe works best on all modern browsers IE>8.

```
downloadUrl = "http://example.com/download/file.zip";
var downloadFrame = document.createElement("iframe"); 
downloadFrame.setAttribute('src',downloadUrl);
downloadFrame.setAttribute('class',"screenReaderText"); 
document.body.appendChild(downloadFrame);
```

`class="screenReaderText"` is my class to style content that is present but not viewable.

css:

```
.screenReaderText { 
  border: 0; 
  clip: rect(0 0 0 0); 
  height: 1px; 
  margin: -1px; 
  overflow: hidden; 
  padding: 0; 
  position: absolute; 
  width: 1px; 
}
```

same as .visuallyHidden in html5boilerplate

I prefer this to the javascript window.open method because if the link is broken the iframe method simply doesn't do anything as opposed to redirecting to a blank page saying the file could not be opened.

```
window.open(downloadUrl, 'download_window', 'toolbar=0,location=no,directories=0,status=0,scrollbars=0,resizeable=0,width=1,height=1,top=0,left=0');
window.focus();
```

Comment: Nice.  The hiding styles seem a bit excessive. But I guess you REALLY don't want to see that frame. :)

Answer (score 9):

Using HTML5 **Blob** Object-URL File API:

**NOTE.** *Please note that this will not work in StackOverflow Snippets, but will work in the browser or [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/loretoparisi/zau2pemk/1/)*

```
/**
 * Save a text as file using HTML <a> temporary element and Blob
 * @see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49988202/macos-webview-download-a-html5-blob-file
 * @param fileName String
 * @param fileContents String JSON String
 * @author Loreto Parisi
*/
var saveBlobAsFile = function(fileName, fileContents) {
    if (typeof(Blob) != 'undefined') { // using Blob
      var textFileAsBlob = new Blob([fileContents], {
        type: 'text/plain'
      });
      var url;
      var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
      downloadLink.download = fileName;
      if (window.webkitURL != null) {
        url = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(textFileAsBlob);
        downloadLink.href = url
        console.log(downloadLink.href)
      } else {
        url = window.URL.createObjectURL(textFileAsBlob);
        downloadLink.href = url
        //downloadLink.onclick = document.body.removeChild(event.target);
        downloadLink.style.display = "none";
        document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
      }
      downloadLink.click();
      window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    } else {
      var pp = document.createElement('a');
      pp.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(fileContents));
      pp.setAttribute('download', fileName);
      pp.onclick = document.body.removeChild(event.target);
      pp.click();
    }
  } //saveBlobAsFile
```

```html
<script>
  /**
   * Save a text as file using HTML <a> temporary element and Blob
   * @see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49988202/macos-webview-download-a-html5-blob-file
   * @param fileName String
   * @param fileContents String JSON String
   * @author Loreto Parisi
   */
  var saveBlobAsFile = function(fileName, fileContents) {
    if (typeof(Blob) != 'undefined') { // using Blob
      var textFileAsBlob = new Blob([fileContents], {
        type: 'text/plain'
      });
      var url;
      var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
      downloadLink.download = fileName;
      if (window.webkitURL != null) {
        url = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(textFileAsBlob);
        downloadLink.href = url
        console.log(downloadLink.href)
      } else {
        url = window.URL.createObjectURL(textFileAsBlob);
        downloadLink.href = url
        //downloadLink.onclick = document.body.removeChild(event.target);
        downloadLink.style.display = "none";
        document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
      }
      downloadLink.click();
      window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    } else {
      var pp = document.createElement('a');
      pp.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(fileContents));
      pp.setAttribute('download', fileName);
      pp.onclick = document.body.removeChild(event.target);
      pp.click();
    }
  } //saveBlobAsFile

  function download() {
    console.log("download");
    var jsonObject = {
      "name": "John",
      "age": 31,
      "city": "New York"
    };
    var fileContents = JSON.stringify(jsonObject, null, 2);
    var fileName = "data.json";

    saveBlobAsFile(fileName, fileContents);
    return false;
  }
</script>
<button id="download" onclick="download()">Download JSON</button>
```

Comment: I feel this is the best way to do it !!

Comment: It is also a good practice to call `URL.revokeObjectURL(url)`, when the file is no longer needed to free up the memory

Comment: This method is really only appropriate for smallish files, as it's likely that the entire file will sit in-memory.

Comment: @Brad that's definitively correct, the blob will sit in the Browser's memory. It should be resident in the memory reserved to the Tab when the code is running, hence it should be offloaded when the tab is in background, but as soon as that Tab is in foreground the memory will be loaded back.

Answer (score 6):

Modifying the location of window might cause some issue especially when you have a persistent connection like websocket. So I always resort to good old iframe solution.

**HTML**

```
<input type="button" onclick="downloadButtonClicked()" value="Download"/>
...
...
...
<iframe style="display:none;" name="hiddenIframe" id="hiddenIframe"></iframe>
```

**Javascript**

```
function downloadButtonClicked() {
    // Simulate a link click
    var url = 'your_download_url_here';
    var elem = document.createElement('a');
    elem.href = url;
    elem.target = 'hiddenIframe';
    elem.click();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If the link is to a valid file url, simply assigning window.location.href will work.

However, sometimes the link is not valid, and an iFrame is required.

Do your normal event.preventDefault to prevent the window from opening, and if you are using jQuery, this will work:

```
$('<iframe>').attr('src', downloadThing.attr('href')).appendTo('body').on("load", function() {
   $(this).remove();
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Best solution as per new chrome specification https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/02/chrome-65-deprecations

Vanilla  JavaScript

```
public static downloadFile(url: string): void {
     const xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
     xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = () => {
       if (xmlHttp.readyState === 4 && xmlHttp.status === 200) {
         const blobUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(xmlHttp.response);
         const e = document.createElement('a');
         e.href = blobUrl;
         e.download = blobUrl.substr(blobUrl.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
         document.body.appendChild(e);
         e.click();
         document.body.removeChild(e);
       }
     };
     xmlHttp.responseType = 'blob';
     xmlHttp.open('GET', url, true);
     xmlHttp.send(null);
   }
```

If you're using angular try this.

```
async downloadBrochure(url: string) {
    try {
      const res = await this.httpClient.get(url, { responseType: 'blob' }).toPromise();
      this.downloadFile(res);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e.body.message);
    }
  }

  downloadFile(data) {
    const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(data);
    const e = document.createElement('a');
    e.href = url;
    e.download = url.substr(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    document.body.appendChild(e);
    e.click();
    document.body.removeChild(e);
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

After hours of trying, the function is born :) I had a scenario where I had to display loader in time while the file is preparing for download:

**Working in Chrome, Safari and Firefox**

```
function ajaxDownload(url, filename = 'file', method = 'get', data = {}, callbackSuccess = () => {}, callbackFail = () => {}) {
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        method: 'GET',
        xhrFields: {
            responseType: 'blob'
        },
        success: function (data) {
            // create link element
            let a = document.createElement('a'), 
                url = window.URL.createObjectURL(data);

            // initialize 
            a.href = url;
            a.download = filename;

            // append element to the body, 
            // a must, due to Firefox
            document.body.appendChild(a);

            // trigger download
            a.click();

            // delay a bit deletion of the element
            setTimeout(function(){
                window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
                document.body.removeChild(a);
            }, 100);

            // invoke callback if any 
            callbackSuccess(data);
        },
        error: function (err) {
            // invoke fail callback if any
            callbackFail(err)
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;url=http://site.com/file.ext">
```

This way works on all browsers (i think) and let you put a message like: "If the download doesn't start in five seconds, click here."

If you need it to be with javascript.. well...

```
document.write('<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;url=http://site.com/file.ext">');
```

Regards

Comment: Wow mate, this response is brilliant and exactly what I needed. Thanks from over a decade later

Answer (score 0):

the absolute easiest way to do this that i found, is to have  a link with the download function. I think the support for this is decent. so you literally set your link as such:

```
<a href="path/to/file.ext" download="filename.ext">Click to download</a>
```

if you have a div or something that you want to download the file by clicking on, then have your javascript generate a confirm/cancel dialog where the confirm button is your link with the download attribute styled to be a button.
I had a button to download an image on my page with some jquery that worked like this:

```js
function getSubstring(string, char1, char2) {
  return string.slice(
    string.indexOf(char1) + 1,
    string.lastIndexOf(char2)
  );
}
$(document).on("click", ".downloadImage", function(){
    var img = $(this).closest(".content").find("img").attr("src");
    var src = getSubstring(img, '=', '&');  
    $(".downloadImage").append('<div class="imgQuickDownloader"><a href="'+src+'" class="quickDL" target="_blank" download>Download</a><div class="cancelimgQuickDownloader">Cancel</div></div>');
});
$(document).on("click", ".quickDL, .cancelimgQuickDownloader",function(e){  
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    e.stopPropagation()
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

```css
button {
position:relative;
}
.content img {
width:150px;
}
.imgQuickDownloader {
    width: auto;
    background-color: #DDD;
    right: 0;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 4px;
    cursor:default;
    white-space: nowrap;
    padding:5px
}
.imgQuickDownloader a, .imgQuickDownloader div {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: #4787C6;
    color: #FFF;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 5px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.imgQuickDownloader a:hover, .imgQuickDownloader div:hover {
    background-color: #333;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
<img src="https://www.w3schools.com/images/myw3schoolsimage.jpg" /> <button class="downloadImage">Download</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The other methods mentioned here didn't consistently open the file in a new tab for me. Adding the target attribute as shown below fixed the problem. This may help anyone else in the future if they come across a similar issue.

```js
var link = document.createElement("a");
link.href = res;
link.target = "_blank";
link.click();
link.remove();
```

Answer (score -1):

A small/hidden iframe can work for this purpose.

That way you don't have to worry about closing the pop up.

Comment: const downloadUrl = "url";
const downloadFrame = document.getElementById('download-iframe') || document.createElement("iframe"); 
downloadFrame.setAttribute('src',downloadUrl);
downloadFrame.setAttribute('id',"download-iframe"); 
downloadFrame.style.display = "none";
document.body.appendChild(downloadFrame);

Comment: I tried this script but the download doesn't start for me - just loads in the iframe.