# download the text file instead of opening in the browser

Tags: php, javascript, text

i have one text file:

When i click the **Download** it should download and save it in my local download path.

I have tried.

```
window.open("data.txt");
```

and

```
header("Location:data.txt")
```

But both are open the text file browser it self. I what download the txt file.

Any one please help me..

Thanks

Manikandan.

Comment: Type "php force download" into your favorite search engine.

Comment: You can set a MIME-type on the server like `application/octet-stream`, or set a `Content-Disposition` header with a value like "attachment; filename=someFile.txt" to force a download of any content-type.

Comment: check this if it helps to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066452/easiest-way-to-open-a-download-window-without-navigating-away-from-the-page

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but it is not working.

Comment: Please help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http headers may solve your problem,
 just referr

```
 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields
```

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```
$file = "data.txt";
$text = file_get_contents($file);
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$file\"");
echo $text;
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you use this Jquery plugin http://jdownloadplugin.com/ to do the file download. It has many additional cool features for file downloading from web.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using apache and want to enforce downloading the txt files instead of opening them in browser.
you can do using .htaccess

```
AddType application/octet-stream .txt
```

Answer (score -1):

I can tell you that you need to set header content-disposition as file attachment, but I do not know how to do it from JavaScript.