# File download - ExtJs 4.2.3

Tags: javascript, extjs, download

I'm using ExtJs 4.2.3.
In my web application I need to download files.
In order to do that I'm using a 'FileDownloader' component defined as in post 
[fileDownloader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7740146/extjs-4-how-to-download-a-file-using-ajax)

The code is:

```
Ext.define('myApp.FileDownload', {
   extend: 'Ext.Component',
   alias: 'widget.FileDownloader',
   autoEl: {
      tag: 'iframe',
      cls: 'x-hidden',
      src: Ext.SSL_SECURE_URL
},

load: function(config) {

    var e = this.getEl();
    e.dom.src = config.url +
        (config.params ? '?' + Ext.Object.toQueryString(config.params) : '');

        console.log('in FileDownloader - src: ' + e.dom.src);

        e.dom.onLoad = function() {
        if(e.dom.contentDocument.body.childNodes[0].wholeText == '404') {
            Ext.Msg.show({ 
                title: 'Attachment missing',
                msg: 'File cannot be found on the server !',
                buttons: Ext.Msg.OK,
                icon: Ext.MessageBox.ERROR
            });
        };
    };

}
```

});

I call it by code:

```
downloader.load({
   url: src
});
```

where src is complete path to file.

If I download Word, Excel, PDF files it's working well, file reference is visualized in download bar of browser, but with other data types (ex. .txt, .jpg) it doesn't do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's no a question about Extjs or js, it's the server's reponse. See this [download the text file instead of opening in the browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6921953/download-the-text-file-instead-of-opening-in-the-browser)