# Downloading a file (Excel file) with store.load? (ExtJS 4.1)

Tags: javascript, ajax, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

I need to download a file from a grid using a button in window. In order to send the filter parameters I use store.load however it doesn't download the file but it tries to read it. Is there any solution?

```
store.load({
 params: {
  startExel: parseInt(Ext.getCmp('startE').getValue())
 }
});
```

startExel is an extra parameter in order to indicate that I want to download an Excel file.

Comment: Is the excel file generated by a script or is it an actual file on the server? You could just wrap an <a> tag around the data in the grid cell and direct the href to the file or script

Comment: @gunnx, the Excel file is generated serverside using the parameters send from the extjs.

Comment: why are you using the store.load could you not just use Ext.ajax instead passing the params needed.

Comment: I don't know how to get the parameters. Too much of them, some appear some times and some not. Plus they are JSON enceded. I'm looking for a simple solution.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think its possible to do this by simple configuration changes. Because stores are loaded via AJAX calls.

Here is an idea for you:

1. Return a `JSON` object with file download url as the response to store load request. Not the actual file contents.

   `{ success = false, url='...'}`
2. In client side handle the store load failure then identify and extract the returned url. You may have to tweak reader configuration a little.
3. Call `window.open(url)` to initiate the file download.

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066452/easiest-way-to-open-a-download-window-without-navigating-away-from-the-page) from SO.

Answer (score 0):

On the server end when returning the file include the following header:

```
Content-disposition: attachment
```

Comment: I use http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/ I think it is related with the request itself.

Comment: It has `Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="01simple.xlsx"`