# forcedownload and load new page

Tags: php, redirect, header, download, refresh

Simple enough question I hope.

I am using the following type of code to force download:

```
if ($ext = ppt){                        
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename= '$filename'");
header('Content-type: application/vnd.ms-powerpoint');
readfile('$file');
```

However, what I really need, is to force the download AND redirect to a new page.

The previous script is currently ON the page I want to redirect to. I have a link to that page.  What I want is so that, as the user goes their it forces the download.  However, right now what I get is, that INSTEAD of the user seeing the page it ONLY forces the download.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've gathered, launching the download will effectively block you from doing anything further from that script.

Your best option is to make the download script a separate page and just load the new page from your link. Then from the new page, open the download page in a new window/tab ([this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1066461/628267) is a good example of how to do it). This is the way most download sites work, like Sourceforge.