# onclick of anchor, download document in same window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, download

I want to prompt user to save data [it could be anything like:- image, pdf, excel sheet etc] in same window.

I don't want to use **HTML5 DOWNLOAD** option as this is not valid for all the browsers.

For example:-

I want to prompt user to download google logo, as per below code.

```
<a href="https://www.google.co.in/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png"> Download Google Logo</a>
```

But it will not download Google icon although it will redirect to that link.

Please suggest!!

---

As per my requirement, target="_blank" or iframe will not solve my concern. I want user will simply download any file in the same page.

Comment: You can't force the user to download the content of an external link.

Comment: This is just an example. Actually, there is requirement as per my project that there is a DOWNLOAD link. On click of that link user will get the concerned things like image, pdf , excel etc.

Comment: a) _"don't want to use HTML5 DOWNLOAD option"_ , b) _"Actually, there is requirement as per my project that there is a DOWNLOAD link"_ Which is requirement ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [easiest way to open a download window without navigating away from the page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066452/easiest-way-to-open-a-download-window-without-navigating-away-from-the-page)

Comment: As per my project, there is a grid which allow user to download content from website. There is a download link on the table

----------------------------------------------------------------
#    |   Content        |      Action
----------------------------------------------------------------
1          |      Image               |      <a href="image.jpg"> Download </a>
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1   |    Excel File    |      <a href="image.jpg"> Download </a>


Now its opening in new page. I want it should download in same page

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `href` of `a` element to `base64` `data URI` of image , with `type` set to `"application/octet-stream"` , `target` set to `"_self"`

```html
<a href="data:application/octet-stream;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABUAAAAWCAYAAAAvg9c4AAAABHNCSVQICAgIfAhkiAAAACRJREFUOI1j/M/A8J+ByoCJ2gaOGjpq6Kiho4aOGjpq6GA2FAAxTAIqi7SS4AAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" target="_self">Download image</a>
```

Comment: but when you run this code it will download unknown file which didn't solve my concern and how I encode path as you are showing?

Comment: _"but when you run this code it will download unknown file"_ If utilized  `download` attribute could suggest file name to user at "Save File" dialog . _"how I encode path as you are showing"_ If requested resource has `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header could use `XMLHttpRequest` , request file as `Blob` , alternatively , download file , convert to `base64` string , `data URI` , use as string at `a` element `href` attribute

Answer (score 0):

Use the iFrame method.

```
<iframe id="download" hidden><\iframe>

<a href="javascript:document.getElementById('download').src = 'file-path'>whatever<\a>
```

-EDIT-

Using the iframe method will not take you to a different page.