# Open a download window and send cookies without navigating away from the page

Tags: javascript, cookies

Calling javascript function [window.location.assign(url);](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066452/easiest-way-to-open-a-download-window-without-navigating-away-from-the-page) almost does my job except for one problem - Firefox and Chromium do not send out cookie to server.  Server can not determine access privileges without cookies.

How do I send cookies along with URL as the request to server and open a download window without navigating away from the page?

[Edit] This an invalid question. Please ignore it! Browsers do send cookies along with the URL to server. It is my server code that fails to catch the incoming cookies.

Comment: What, AJAX you mean?

Comment: Well use AJAX then

Comment: @AlonEitan In deep contemplation...