# How to come back to parent tab right after open new tab?

Tags: javascript, html

I need to open a download page in a new tab, and after the download is complete, it should close and will come back to parent page automatically. But, I do not want the user to stay in the download blank page. 
I just want to open a download tab and get the user back to the application's tab.

I've tried,

```
let win = window.open('http://google.com', '_blank');

win.opener(); // x

win.parent(); // x

win.opener.parent.focus(); // x

window.focus() // x
```

but nothing works, is it possible to do that? If so, then how?

(I need to support IE9+, FF and chrome)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [easiest way to open a download window without navigating away from the page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066452/easiest-way-to-open-a-download-window-without-navigating-away-from-the-page)

Comment: From suggested answer: `window.location.assign('http://google.com');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use
`window.location.assign(downloadPageUrl);`