# Custom download name with Javascript or JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I know how to use the `<a href="file.jpg" download="name">` block in HTML, but I'm afraid that will not work for this project.

I would like to have a download link which will (unsurprisingly) download a file.  I would also like a text box on the screen that will allow the user to name the file that thay download.

The site would look something like this:

```html
Name:<input type="text" name="Name" value="Custon Name">
<br>
<button type="button">Download</button>
```

I want the `<button>` block to use `onclick"function()"` in order to download the file.  The function will get the text from the text box and use it to name the file when downloading it.  The thing I need help with is finding a way to name the file using Javascript or JQuery in the same way that `download="name"` would.

I've looked for a while for a way to do this, but no luck.  Is this project possible? If so, how is it done?

Comment: Is there at least a way to change the value of `download="name"`?

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help.

Comment: @Dijkgraaf how is downloading a file a security hole?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well you can do it by creating the `a` element dynamically and setting the inputted name as its `download` attribute:

```
function downloadIt() {
  var name = document.getElementsByName("Name")[0].value;
  if (name && name !=='') {
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.download = name;
    link.href ="file.png";  
    link.click();
  }
}
```

This is a [working **Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/chsdk/cwy3gxz4/) and you can check [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43523297/3669624) for file download with JavaScript too.

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can. Let's add a hidden link in the page dynamically and click on it, thus emulating the effect of the "download" attribute.

HTML:

```
Name:<input type="text" name="Name" id="myName" value="Custom Name">
<br>
<button type="button" onclick="download()">Download</button>
```

JS:

```
function download() {
  var a = document.createElement("a");
  a.href = "myfile.png";
  a.download = document.getElementById("myName").value;
  document.body.appendChild(a);
  a.click();
  document.body.removeChild(a);
}
```

Working example (tested on Chrome): https://jsfiddle.net/72qepvng/