# jQuery: extract file name from an href link when adding "download" attribute

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am using generated html that contains a link to a file with the `.dxf` suffix:

`<a href="http://example.com/filetodownload.dxf">Download File</a>`

Since I can't change the dynamically created html, I'm using this to add the download attribute to those href links:

```
jQuery('a[href*=".dxf"]').each(function() {
jQuery("a").attr("download", "downloadedfile.dxf");
});
```

This forces the browser to open a "download and save" dialogue.

The problem is that I want the download attribute to have the name of the file in the link, i.e. `filetodownload.dxf` and not the default `downloadedfile.dxf` in the jQuery function.

How can I get jQuery to use the real file name? Can I call a variable that is the actual file name? How do I extract the file name from the link?

I don't want a box on the page to name the downloaded file, like [Custom download name with Javascript or JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44555950/custom-download-name-with-javascript-or-jquery)

I can't get the file name from the URL in the browser, since the file is a html download link, not a URL, like
[js function to get filename from url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/511761/js-function-to-get-filename-from-url/2480287)

Comment: ""I can't get the file name from the URL, since th file is a download link, not a URL" — That doesn't make sense. The `href` attribute **must** be a URL A link is just a thing you click on to navigate to something at a URL.

Comment: Thanks, I clarified that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `jQuery("a").attr("download", "downloadedfile.dxf");` in a `.each()` updates ALL the elements' `download` attribute *multiple times*, not just the one you're trying to update.

You'll have to pass in the element into your `.each` callback, or use `$(this)` to keep refer to the "current" element in the collection you're iterating over.

```
jQuery('a[href*=".dxf"]').each(function(i, $elem) {
    var pathname;
    if (typeof URL !== 'undefined') {
        var url = new URL($elem.attr('href'));
        // Note: Using URL.pathname strips off the #hash and ?foo=bar arguments
        // e.g. 'https://example.com/foo/bar/baz.xls?id=2&a=b#hash'
        //   -> 'baz.xls'
        pathname = url.pathname.split('/').pop();
    } else {
        // must be IE11 or older (~1.38% user share as of 2020-07-08)
        pathname = $elem.attr('href');
    }
    var filename = pathname.split('/').pop();
    $elem.attr("download", filename);
});
```

Note: The `URL` class isn't supported in IE 11 or older.

Comment: That's interesting about IE 11; do kmoser or Тимофей's answers support IE11 and older?

Comment: Added IE11 support.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
jQuery('a[href*=.dxf]').each(function () {
    $(this).attr("download", this.href.split("/").pop().split("#")[0].split("?")[0]);
});
```

Got the splitter from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36756650/9677724).

Comment: Thanks, but see amphetamachine's answer for the issue with each.

Comment: @BlueDogRanch Actually this will work just fine too; `$(this)` refers to the element for that iteration.

Answer (score 1):

For each `<a>` tag, use a regexp to extract the filename in the `href` attribute and set the `download` value to that:

```
jQuery('a[href*=".dxf"]').each(function() {
    let url = $(this).attr('href');
    let filename = url.split('/').pop() // https://stackoverflow.com/a/17143667/378779
    console.log(filename);
    $(this).attr("download", filename);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but see amphetamachine's answer for the issue with each.

Comment: @BlueDogRanch Actually this works just fine because they used `$(this)`.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I am understanding you correctly, but this should work:

```
jQuery('a[href*=".dxf"]').each(function() {
    jQuery("a").attr("download", jQuery(this).attr('href').split('/').pop());
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but see amphetamachine's answer for the issue with each.