# Cypress: Detect if <a download> was clicked

Tags: javascript, html, cypress

I have a vue 3 application that offers a file download from the assets folder. Now, in a cypress test I want to make sure that this download actually works as expected, especially the connection with the assets folder (does it work both locally in development mode and also when deployed on the CDN).

The element to trigger the download is an anchor:

```html
 <a href="/images/myw3schoolsimage.jpg" download>
```

[Source](https://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/att_a_download.asp)

Clicking the link pops up the download interface (firefox) where the user can decide whether to open, download etc...

I found this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53835315/how-to-detect-whether-download-was-invoked-when-clicking-on-a) which goes in a similar direction, but not exactly what I'm looking for.

Is it even possible to check this as the actual interaction is done with the browser itself and not the application anymore? Further, can this be checked with cypress as well?

Comment: you're depending on the browser to process that HTML attribute, make sure that is a supported feature of all browsers you want your app/site to be visible - regarding Cypress, there's not much it can't do and remember that in Cypress/Puppeteer/etc you can pass a path to the element, like `a[download]` ... [here's the running test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DVQQZ.png)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the compatibility! I will double check how to change this approach.

And thanks for you suggestion! I've written a similar test now and it works! I'm fairly new to cypress and didnt know you can easily access downloaded files. If you convert your comment in an answer, I can accept it right away ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're depending on the browser to process that HTML attribute, make sure that is a [supported feature of all browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAnchorElement/download) you want your app/site to be visible

regarding **Cypress**, there's not much it can not do and remember that in Cypress/Puppeteer/etc you can pass a path to the element, like `a[download]`

here's the running test

[image]

---

**Cypress** can easily test downloadable files [since version 6.3.0](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/5027#issuecomment-763325232)

---

`./index.html`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>The a download attribute</h1>

<p>Click on the image to download it:<p>
<a href="/myw3schoolsimage.jpg" download>
  <img src="/myw3schoolsimage.jpg" alt="W3Schools" width="104" height="142">
</a>

<p><b>Note:</b> The download attribute is not supported in IE or Edge (prior version 18), or in Safari (prior version 10.1).</p>

</body>
</html>
```

`./cypress/plugins/index.js`

```js
module.exports = (on, config) => {
  on('task', {
    deleteFolder (folderName) {
      console.log('deleting folder %s', folderName)

      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        rmdir(folderName, { maxRetries: 10, recursive: true }, (err) => {
          if (err) {
            console.error(err)

            return reject(err)
          }

          resolve(null)
        })
      })
    },
  })
}
```

`./cypress/integration/w3schools.specs.js`

```js
const path = require('path')

const deleteDownloadsFolder = () => {
    const downloadsFolder = Cypress.config('downloadsFolder')
    cy.task('deleteFolder', downloadsFolder)
}
  
describe('My First Test', () => {
    const downloadsFolder = Cypress.config('downloadsFolder')
    beforeEach(deleteDownloadsFolder)

    it('Visit w3schools example', () => {
        cy.visit('/index.html')
        cy.get('a[download]').click()
        cy.log('**read downloaded file**')

        const filename = path.join(downloadsFolder, 'myw3schoolsimage.jpg')
        cy.readFile(filename, { timeout: 15000 })
            .should('have.length.gt', 50)
    })
})
```