# How to Load from INPUT without page load

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have this code:

```
<input type="submit" onclick="window.location='https://www.example.com/script.php';" value="CLICK HERE" id='dwl_btn_load'>
```

When I press on CLICK HERE the page start to load and run https://www.example.com/script.php.

The script (https://www.example.com/script.php) automatically downloads me a file and takes about 20 seconds while the page is loading.

I want to make this procces without page load if is posible.

I have only 1 input without  tag.

Thank you.

Comment: possibly duplicate question of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066452/easiest-way-to-open-a-download-window-without-navigating-away-from-the-page

Answer (score 0):

Try this using jQuery AJAX Call

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$.ajax({ url: "https://www.example.com/script.php",
        context: document.body,
        success: function(){
           alert("done");
        }});
});
</script>
```

Comment: This example loads the page for 20 seconds until the script is loaded. It's not what I'm looking for

Comment: there are something take more time, so you need to check functions into "script.php", paste content of this PHP Page

Comment: I want to load the whole story of script.php without loading page ... like with ajax