# Get location and/or status when downloading a file via a.click() using javascript

Tags: javascript, vue.js, download, anchor, savefiledialog

I am working on an app in Vue.js 2. I am using a `v-for` with a Vuetify `v-btn` component to call a method called `downloadFile`.

```html
<template v-for="item in items">
  <v-btn @click="downloadFile(item)" v-bind:key="item.filename" small icon>
    <v-icon>mdi-folder-download</v-icon>
  </v-btn>
</template>
```

The `downloadFile` method then opens a dialogue for the user to download the file. For this, I'm using a method described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43523297/7195196) that works for me (I also plan to add a step where the file is generated before downloading).

```js
methods: {
  downloadFile(item) {
    let link = document.createElement('a')
    link.href = `https://localhost:5000/static/${item.filename}`
    link.download = `${item.filename}`
    link.click()
  }
}
```

This works fine in the sense that it prompts user to select a destination to download the file to.

**The problem:**

However, I would like to do some action based on whether the user really clicks the download button or cancels the download, i.e., the code could look something like this

```js
methods: {
  downloadFile(item) {
    let link = document.createElement('a')
    link.href = `https://localhost:5000/static/${item.filename}`
    link.download = `${item.filename}`
    link.click()

    if (file_downloaded) {
      this.$set(item, 'downloaded', true)
      this.$set(item, 'filepath', path_selected_by_user)
    }
  }
}
```

This would then trigger the UI update, e.g. check some checkbox and show the filepath somewhere.

**The questions:**

- Is there some way I get to know whether the user really downloads the file or cancels the download?
- Is there a way to get the location to which the user downloads the file?

**Edit:**

It was suggested to me to check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1106377/7195196). This thread does not solve my problem, as the problem there is to show some sort of a waiting screen while the file is generated on the server and then hide it when the download dialogue is open.

My problem is that once the download dialogue is open, I want to know whether the user clicks `Save` or `Cancel`, and if they click `Save`, what the path they've chosen is.