# Open pdf from a link (colissimo)

Tags: jquery

I want to open a pdf on the same page when I click on a link generated by colissimo. (https://ws.colissimo.fr/)
I want to open it on the active tab, no dialog should open.
I want to do this in jquery, I tried a lot of solutions like "window.location.open" or "window.location.replace" but nothing works.

I have a link who call my function on click :

```
<p id="btnPrintPdf">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="showPdfEtiquetteRetour(<?php echo $order->commande_id; ?>, <?php echo $multi_transp; ?>, '<?php echo $bon_retour_numero; ?>', true)"></a>
</p>
```

and this is a part of my jquery function :

```
$.ajax({
        url : path_relative_root + 'ajax_create_etiquette.php',
        type : 'post',
        data : data,
        success : function (res) {
            if ( res.substr(0,5) == 'false' ) {
                alert('js_error_return_label');
            } else {
                if (show_pdf) {
                    window.open(res);
                } else {
                    location.reload();
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

res is a link to the pdf

Comment: please show me your code

Comment: I added my code

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Easiest way to open a download window without navigating away from the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066452/easiest-way-to-open-a-download-window-without-navigating-away-from-the-page)

Comment: No, the problem stay the same, the pdf is download in place of just open it