# Return multiple values python flask

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to return a file and changing the template in Flask.

```
return send_file(myfile, as_attachment=True), return render_template("template.html")
```

But it gives me an error.
If I try to make 2 `return`s like this:

```
return send_file(myfile, as_attachment=True)
return render_template("template.html")
```

or

```
return render_template("template.html")
return send_file(myfile, as_attachment=True)
```

It doesn't work eitherway.
How do I fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Well, I'm not really that good, that's why I'm asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > You only get one response per request. You can either send a file, or send a new page.

Bear the above in mind by @Tim Roberts.

> > How do I send the file and then send the new page?.

`A long possible ride I suggest you do something like this (Note you use another view for sending the file too)`.

```
    # ...
    if request.GET.get("send", None):
        return send_file(myfile, as_attachment=True)
    return render_template("template.html")
```

In the template use ajax to make GET request to the view

```
ajax.get({
    "/the-view-url/?send=file",
    success: function(data) {
    // do whatever you want with data (file)
    }
```

Tada !! you can now return a response or a file.

I suggest you consider this:

> > It seems like you need to learn Python's fundamentals. –
> > mac13k

Answer (score 0):

You only get one response per request.  You can either send a file, or send a new page.

Comment: How do I send the file and then send the new page?

Comment: You can use Javascript to create a download link and click on it, then do a `window.locations = ` to move to a new URL.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066452/easiest-way-to-open-a-download-window-without-navigating-away-from-the-page